# Multiple animation on one rigged character

Tags: animation, rigging

I have used blender for years (modeling/texturing), I know how to rig, but I never needed to animate anything. In the past I sometimes move bones (mostly for fun) but I don't know how to deal if **I want to make different animations with the same character**.

as first task, I want to make my character walking, running and waving.

(I'm using blender 2.71 on linux)

Comment: You should split this in to 2 questions one on the Multiple animations, and one on exporting the animation to collada.

Comment: @David ok I will edit my question. Actually I shall wait for second part

Answer (score 2):

You use the [action editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet/Action) (a sub part of the dopesheet) to create multiple actions. An object can have one action associated with it at a time so remember to add a fake user to keep other actions.

Once you have setup multiple actions you use the [NLA editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA) to combine and repeat a mixture of actions for the final animation.

It is also possible to use multiple blend files with linked copies of your character that each contain one animation for a shot. After each shot is rendered out you edit them together into the final video.

Answer (score 0):

The [Makehuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) project exports to Collada and to Blender exchange (mhx). It can also rig your models for [Rigify](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify) in Blender. Making any exported Makehuman model move convincingly (walk, run, etc.) in blender is as simple as downloading a BVH [motion capture file](http://accad.osu.edu/research/mocap/mocap_data.htm) and associating it with the rig using the [Motion Capture Addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/Motion_Capture_Tools) and [MakeWalk](http://www.makehuman.org/doc/node/mhblendertools_makewalk_basic_workflow.html).

Comment: you give me a lot of links, I need to explore them and see if I can do what I need. But I still would like to know how I can create several animation associated to one model. I don't need a complex example like walking, a simple example with two animation for a same model, like moving a bone in one direction and moving a bone in an other direction, or another bone, should be fine.